# Show standard Sharepoint Ribbon in a custom list form

Tags: ribbon

I developed in VS 2010 a custom list form and I want to use the "standard" Sharepoint Ribbon, ie, the same Ribbon used in all list forms withe the same buttons.

It's possible do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. In my case the was a visual studio solution that contained a list with custom forms.

```
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\CustomDisplayForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\CustomEditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"/>
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\CustomNewForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"/>
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

And the pages referenced all are inherited from WebPartPage.
The solution put these pages into {SharePointRoot}\Template\Pages.

Please let me know if you haven't got the idea and need more details.

Comment: It was one of my first trials.
When I try to open a created item (my custom form is a display form), the form is open with no ribbon.

Comment: 1) Ensure that your page inherits from a webpart page

Comment: 2) Make sure that there is actually a listformwebpart on the page

Comment: 3) hide the listforwebpart on prerender. This solution is quite dirty but when you realize how it all works you will be able to come to the idea how to make it more clear. Like my team and me did :) I wish you good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It works ;o)

Comment: Hi Maks.
I have another problem: in the form to new items, the save button doesn't save, because sharepoint is validating mandatory fields in the hidden webpart, and, this fields are empty. 
I have the same formfields in my custom form, but sharepoint/save button is looking first to the fields in the hidden webpart.
Do you have any trick to bypass this situation?

Comment: you might try make all fields optional and enforce your own custom validation to gain even more flexibility and avoid validation of the hidden webpart. also you will have to override the "raisepostbackevent" method of your form and do your custom logic to process data from your form. check the command of the postback (it may be "EditItem" or any else the ribbon emits) and do the corresponding logic. you can also try to decompile the listform webpart and see how it actually enables ribbon and take its code but this has a risk to face a lot of "sharepoint magic" that cannot be used outside SP.

Comment: Thank's again. Your sugestions were very usefull.

Comment: Are they worth accepting? :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I have an idea for this task - you can implement your custom form UI as a webpart and add it to a standard list item form. Then you need to hide (but not delete) a standart data form on that page. The idea behind it is to let the dataform webpart do the work for you - on a standard page it requests the needed tabs from the ribbon.</strike>. I've realized that it doesn't work because in this case you will not be able to control item save button - it will be rendered by DataFormwebPart. :(